# Protect Image Resources in class library

Tags: c#, resources

I have a class library that contains several PNG images with their Build Action set to Resource.  How do you protect or hide these images so that external application cannot load them using a pack uri?   In short, I want my class library to be able to access the images but have them unreachable externally by applications that reference my assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Change the access modifier to internal on your .resx, it will let you access to your resources only from your library

Comment: The resources are png images.  There is no resx file.